# Does Postgres cache plans even when query is different?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am trying optimizations on my PostgreSQL queries. One of the optimizations I tried was the removal of functions as I have read that functions like `coalesce` slow down query performance.

I ran the query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2
      ON t2.org_id = t1.org_id AND t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.service = t1.service
   LEFT JOIN table3 t3
      ON t3.org_id = t1.org_id AND t3.user_id = t1.user_id AND t3.service = t1.service
WHERE t1.org_id = :orgId
  AND t1.service = 's1'
  AND COALESCE(t2.rgid, '') = :rgid
  AND t1.status IN ('active', 'error');
```

and then replaced the `coalesce` function and ran

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2
      ON t2.org_id = t1.org_id AND t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.service = t1.service
   LEFT JOIN table3 t3
      ON t3.org_id = t1.org_id AND t3.user_id = t1.user_id AND t3.service = t1.service
WHERE t1.org_id = '1234567'
  AND t1.service = 's1'
  AND (t2.rgid = :rgid OR ( t2.rgid IS NULL AND :rgid =''))
  AND t1.status IN ('active', 'error');
```

I saw a good performance improvement because of the change and thought the optimization worked. But few days later I ran the second command again and it took much more time than last time. And i was wondering, did the speed increase because of caching?

However, since the two queries are different, how can it use the cache result of one for the other?

Edit: there is no index on the column inside `coalesce`, and not planning to create one either.

Comment: can you pate result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) ?

Comment: Re "did the speed increase beacause of caching" - how many times you ran your query? I don't know about PostgreSQL and your hardware, but I have seen similar subsequent queries on same data being faster due to the disk caching (which often indicates insufficient RAM on server).

Comment: I don't think any database uses cached results from a dissimilar query.  More likely, you just had the data already loaded into memory.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , how is that different ? Isnt that the same as caching ?

Comment: This is very likely just an effect of caching, because your construction is (if anything) probably slower than the `coalesce`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe what makes you say that ?

Comment: Also how does caching work for different queries, it doesnt make much sense

Comment: It is not the statement or its execution plan that are cached, but table and index data are cached in RAM. Reading data from RAM is faster than reading from disk. Anyway, without seeing the execution plans, this is all guessing.

Comment: It might be the OS caching Drive access

Comment: @Denise . . . The difference is caching the *inputs* into the query rather than the *result set*.  I interpreted your question as asking about the result set rather than warm caches of the input data.